# Can I invert the colours of the phone screen within my application?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

As part of my first WP7 app, I'm giving the user configuration options to alert them to the completion of a task:  currently I have the option to vibrate the phone, but I would like to 'flash' the screen my inverting the colours and back again.

However, I can't figure out how to invert the screen colours.  Is this possible?

Comment: You could write a pixel shader to accomplish this. However, even though pixel shaders are supported in Silverlight 3, they are not currently supported in WP7. I'm only suggesting this because if they end up adding support then this would be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture your app's screen as a WriteableBitmap, invert the colors and display it in an animation for a short period of time. Inverting colors of a bitmap would be like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/9C08D28C-5E5D-4E0D-B4DB-2F343FE4019C) (sample is for WPF).

Answer (score 3):

*Commentary portion:* 
Why do you want to do the "flash"?  Wouldn't some other standard notification be more appropriate? I've never seen a flash behavior on a phone, so if i saw the colors invert and go back in an app, i'd figure there was something wrong with my phone!

**Answer portion:**
What about just making a rectangle the full size of the screen that is white but partially transparent?  or black and partially transparent, or both.

That way you don't need to "invert" anything, simply animate the opacity of the rectangles(s)

If you do it that way you could get different effects, like different color overlays for different conditions?

Comment: I want a silent, visual alert that can be seen across a room if required.  I go with the philosophy of allowing the user as much choice in how to be alerted as possible; if you configured an alert to flash the phone UI you wouldn't assume anything was wrong with the phone.

Comment: My answer probably should have been a comment since it was a question.

Is it going to continually flash until someone responds?  if not, then you look away for a second and you'd never notice the flash.